# Sudo: "Operation not permitted" when program is started as a service, but working when manually started. Why?

Tags: permissions, systemd, sudo

I need to be able to exec a command as sudo  (e.g. `sudo echo 'toto'`)  in a custom go program. I've added my user in `/etc/sudoers` and it works just fine, when I login as my user and run the program manually.

However, when I run the exact same program from a systemd service, I get the following error:

```
sudo: unable to change to root gid: Operation not permitted
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

My service is basic:

```
[Unit]
Description=test sudo

[Service]
User=test
Group=test
ExecStart=/etc/test/test
```

and in my `/etc/sudoers`:

```
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"

root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

test        ALL = NOPASSWD: ALL
```

What's the difference between manually running the program as my user versus the same program started as a service?

Testing on Ubuntu 18.04 and Debian 9.9

Comment: Ah. My first guess was the sudo `requiretty` option, but actually I don't think that would match the error message.  Since you mention Ubuntu, I suspect this might be AppArmor.  I don't know how to use AppArmor :-(.

Answer (score 3):

I finally found the issue: my service was adding a list of `CapabilityBoundingSet` for some reason which was restricting the `sudo` operations.